# How to open files of Filezilla in current open Aptana Studio 3

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, aptana, filezilla, aptana3

When I change the configuration of filezilla to **open files in Aptana Studio 3**, it starts a **new process** Aptana, and do not mind that is open, ie a new workspace.

How to set to open in a **new tab in Aptana** that is already open (running?)

*And if possible, how to do the same for other files, for example, to configure when you open an html file by Nautilus or the terminal, open a new tab.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Edit > Settings > File Editing > File type associations > Custom filetype associations write:

"file extension" "Aptana Studio Path"

example:

html \usr\bin\Aptana