# Filezilla opens new aptana process

Tags: aptana, filezilla

My problem is basically the same than this one but on windows 7:
[How to open files of Filezilla in current open Aptana Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969575/how-to-open-files-of-filezilla-in-current-open-aptana-studio-3)

Every file that opened from Filezilla launch a new Aptana3 process, which crashes because the workspace is already used in the other instance.

I had the same issue before but can't remember how I solved it.

I have another computer with Windows7 where it works fine, I compared Filezilla and Aptana settings and they are all the same.

In Filezilla settings I have:

- File Editing:

  Use custom editor: [aptana path]

  Always use custom editor

  Filetype associations:

  Inherit system filtype associations

  Custom filetype associations is empty

Again, that works fine with the same settings on another computer...

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in the program - [Bug Discussion](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2084-opening-new-file-opens-new-aptana). Apparently there is a fix but to get to it you have to register at Aptana to view the workaround. Too many hoops and bugs for me so am going to uninstall Aptana and use Netbeans from now on.